# How can I define an order in my GitHub checks?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-app

I have multiple GitHub checks. One of them is [mergify](https://mergify.com). It merges the PR is all defined checks are successful. However in my case there is a different check that only starts after a minute or so, which is why mergify always misses it.

How can I make sure that mergify starts with some delay or better that it starts as the last GitHub app

Answer (score 0):

You can't and should not do that.

If you wrote your Mergify config with something like `"#check-failure!=0"` or `#check-pending!=0` this is exactly why the Mergify documentation states that you should not do that.

The only secure way to merge a pull request automatically is to list all the CI you expect to pass to have it merged.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring that my test is in `check-success` worked.